# windows 7 phone - close keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I programmatically close the onscreen keyboard for my WP7 app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way would be to change the focus to be away from the TextBox that's causing it to be open, with .Focus on some other control. You can put it on a non visual control if you prefer.

Comment: There's a really good example of this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/07/02/programmatically-dismiss-the-sip-keyboard-in-windows-phone-silverlight-app.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a page that has no other sensible control to switch focus to, setting IsEnabled = false (and then back to true straight away if you want) on the TextBox which has focus will also close the SIP.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-hide-the-soft-keyboard-in-a-windows-phone-app

You will love this, It solved my problem when search clicked

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.